# How to use a specific category archive index as the site front page?

Tags: template-hierarchy, homepage

I investigated Wordpress hierarchy and have created a php file called category-image-gallery.php the link to this is http://www.phoneographer.org/category/image-gallery/ having uploaded it and added it to my custom menu. I would like to set this as my home page but it's not listed as a Page in my reading settings screen (because it's not a static page I guess) so I can't select it. Is there any way to set this php 'page' (I guess page isn't strictly the correct term) as my home page?

Many thanks.

Skip.

Comment: Would it be accurate to say that what you want to do is: **Use a specific category archive index as the site front page**?

Comment: I hope you'll forgive me if I don't use the correct terminology but basically I would like the URL http://www.phoneographer.org/category/image-gallery/ (which is category-image-gallery.php) to become http://www.phoneographer.org - I would include it in my bespoke menu as 'home' with the address http://www.phoneographer.org - hope that answers the question?

Answer (score 3):

Create a file `front-page.php` with the following content:

```
locate_template( 'category-image-gallery.php', TRUE, TRUE );
```

That’s all.

#### For the theme’s `functions.php`

If you want to restrict the front page content to posts from that category, filter the front page query:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_74225_frontpage_categories' );

function wpse_74225_frontpage_categories( $query ) 
{
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && is_front_page() ) 
    {
        $query->set( 'category_name', 'image-gallery' );
    }

    return $query;
}
```

But that would create a copy of your category archive: duplicate content, not a good idea if you want both pages be found in search engines.

To avoid links to that category archive you have to filter `'term_link'` too:

```
add_filter( 'term_link', 'wpse_74225_category_link', 10, 2 );

function wpse_74225_category_link( $link, $term )
{
    if ( 'image-gallery' === $term->slug )
        return home_url();

    return $link;
}
```

Comment: @toscho I've given it a try - front-page.php works fine. I can see that it pulls the correct template to the front page. However, the add_action in functions.php doesn't pull in any posts. The only 'post' that appears is the 'page' currently set as my home page within reading settings in the admin panel. Any ideas? Also within functions.php I have an existing pre_get_posts action which strips various categories from the main 'blog' as they have their own 'page' (image-gallery being one) ... thought I'd mention in case part of the issue.

Comment: You cannot use that for a “static” front page. And yes, other filters will affect this query too, if you don’t test for `is_front_page()`.

Comment: @toscho thank you. I don't want a static front page. I want the template 'category-image-gallery and posts from the 'image-gallery' category to appear in the template. At the moment I have the template and a snippet from my existing front page appearing in it and none of the posts. Can you help further (I do not want to take all your time up). Skip.

Comment: Oh I think I see what you're saying I have to set 'Reading Settings' as front page displays 'your latest posts' rather than a 'static page' as it is at the moment. If I do that though what happens to all the other blog categories after I've filtered in functions.php? Currently I have 'posts page' set to a page called 'blog' but with some categories stripped out - I'm not sure where other posts would appear?

Comment: The other posts will appear on the category archive pages.

Comment: OK got it - so there would be no 'general' blog left on the menu - I call it 'news'. I guess strictly this solution answers my question but losing all other posts from the main menu is quite a cost to pay - for me at least. Thank you though, really appreciate the guidance.

Comment: Quick update, I'm thinking a bespoke unique page template with the appropriate code to write the static elements and pull the correct posts will be the way to go. The front 'static' page would be based on this template but the page itself would contain no content - it would all come from the template. Much messier than what was suggested and a real pain when the theme files are upgraded but I think it will work. I'll tinker tomorrow on something based on an existing theme template.

Comment: Managed to get it working via a new template based on category-image-gallery.php - Static page with all content in the template + posts from the specific category only. Feels quite long winded but was minimal edit in the end.